# page print in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, printing

I am trying to print the page by java script. The code is like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintContent(){
            var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById("divtoprint");
            var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow","width=1200,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
            WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
            WindowObject.document.close();
            WindowObject.focus();
            WindowObject.print();
            WindowObject.close();
        }
    </script>
```

Then I called that function `<a onclick="PrintContent();" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="images/printer.png" alt="Print" title="printer"/></a>`
 Also the contents which I want to print, put within `<div id="divtoprint"> </div>`.

But in this case, I am getting the print page without css style. So how to integrate the css to my print page also? Please help me.

Comment: Use a print stylesheet. This won't be easy the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintContent(){
    var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById("divtoprint");
    var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow","width=1200,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
    WindowObject.document.write('<html><head><title>Printwindow</title>');
    WindowObject.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">');
    WindowObject.document.write('</head><body>');
    WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
    WindowObject.document.write('</body></html>');
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the `link` (or whatever) to your CSS and ensure it has a `media` attribute that includes `print`.

Comment: I am using the style.css for my plain page, where all the css classes have been defined. Now I add the following code as you suggest to add media attribute:<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" /> . Then also it is not working, in the print page.

Comment: @John make sure that you include the print.css file below your primary styles, otherwise they will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        #divtoprint { /** your css code goes here **/ }
        /** other selector style goes here which style you print **/
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the CSS tag to work with all media?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" type="text/css" />
```

Or if you want to be more specific

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen, print" type="text/css" />
```